# Passwordless SSH between users on the same server fails (CentoOS 6.3)

Tags: linux, ssh

I have set passwordless connection from user A on my server to two other users. SSH to one of them works fine, but to the other one it asks for password.
As far as I can tell, both users are the same with ssh files, permissions, etc. setting **StrictModes no** and **UsePAM no** didn't help.

In /var/log/secure I see for the first user:

```
debug1: trying public key file /home/testb/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /home/testb/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
```

And for the second (/myuser/app/ is ~):

```
debug1: trying public key file /myuser/app/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1500/1500 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /myuser/app/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for myuser from ::1 port 38888 ssh2
```

authorized_keys file is the same for both.

Any help would be appreciated.

Eran.

Comment: Why are you using `ssh` to log onto the server you are already logged on to? Is there a specific reason or do you just want to change users?

Comment: It's within a script that usually do ssh to another server. In this specific configuration, both are on same server.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the file /myuser/app/.ssh/authorized_keys has the correct owner and permissions.

It should be readable only for the owner (here: myuser)

```
    chown myuser /myuser/app/.ssh/authorized_keys
    chmod 600 /myuser/app/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: also make sure, wherever your .ssh subdirectory is, it has 700 permissions as well as your user's home directory is not writable by any anyone but the user itself.

Comment: Thank you both. Permissions are already set as you suggested. However, Permissions are the same for the user I can connect and the one I can't. This is what strange here.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this:
http://bugs.centos.org/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=4959

So I run

> restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh

And the problem solved!